# Automatic bookkeeping for exception retries

Tags: exception

Do any languages that support `retry` constructs in exception handling track and expose the number of times their `catch`/`rescue` (and/or `try`/`begin`) blocks have been executed in a particular run?

I find myself counting (and limiting) the number of times a code block is re-executed after an exception often enough that this would be a handy language built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really interesting question.  I did a little research and apparently there is a design pattern called the circuit breaker pattern which was developed to handle such things.  I have never heard of the pattern before and can't find much information about it.

There is a library which handles retrying an event for .NET available, might be worth a look.  Heres a link to an article about it:

http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/1/26/net-circuit-breakers/